# перехват трафика от MMORPG

Tags: php, сервер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть варианты для перехвата  трафика от клиент-серверного приложения? Например, необходимо сделать приложение, которое будет выводить в браузер какие-то данные от игры. У нас есть игра X из которой мне нужно взять данные с внутриигрового рынка(товары, ценник, описание), так же вывести список топ игроков(по уровню или каких либо другим характеристикам). На некоторых сайтах есть такие статистики, так же как пример может служить dotabuf на котором есть подробная статистика акаунтов игроков.(но работать с играми из steam проще т.к. есть api от valve). Как можно сделать что-то подобное, мне бы узнать в какую сторону копать.

Я нашел стать о перехвате трафика из игры с помощью анализа трафика сети, но там нужно еще найти нужную инфу и раскодировать ее.

Comment: Могу ошибаться конечно, но мне кажется проще на питоне побыстрому сделать например с использованием селениума с опцией headless (я так недавно делал бота для годвиля).  Ну или погуглить про скраперы инфу - её полно :-)

Answer (score 0):

Если есть где например на сайте данные о X игре и их игроках и тому подобное то с помощью регулярных выражений вы можете создать приложение или функцию для сохранения этих данных и потом использовать их в своих целях, хранить их в многомерных массивах и оттуда уже перебирать!